# how to find which view breaking constraint in ios 7

Tags: ios, ios7

I applied every constraint to all outlet but getting error when i use my
 project so i totally disappoint can you help me
Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
    (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "",
    "",
    "",
    "",
    "",
    "",
    ""
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in  may also be helpful.

Comment: can you show your constraints in IB or in Code , whichever you used..

Answer (score 0):

Add UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints symbolic breakpoint help you debug autolayout easier !

[image]

[image]